# Gitlab Mirroring 500 error while mirroring from omnibus to kubernetes based Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, mirroring, gitlab-omnibus

I have been trying to mirror Gitlab repository from omnibus gitlab to kubernetes based Gitlab but while mirroring it throws 500 error
while cloning I am using the git repository url as follows
"https://root@gitlab/git-repo-link"
[image: how to replicate]

[image: error]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the logs against that request ID?

Comment: hi attaching correspoding screenshot